# Hot to upload a new font (OFT) file into blender

Tags: text-object

I've designed a font in fontforge and now I need to put it to use. can someone tell me how I can install to font into blender !

Answer (score 1):

Create a text object and in the font section of the text panel you will see four choices for font.  Click the buttons and navigate to your directory.

[image]

The tool tip shows where to click.

I have made the text panel in full zoom.  You can see text choice at the text properties selected at the top.